# How to add breadcrumbs on Category and product details

Tags: magento2, breadcrumbs

I have tried to add breadcrumbs on product category page and also on product details page with following codes but it's not working.

**1. Add following code to theme default.xml and check page.top is not remove**

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
        </referenceContainer>
```

**2. add fallowing code to catalog_category_view.xml**

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs">
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Home</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Home</item>
                    <item name="link" xsi:type="string">{{baseUrl}}</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
            <action method="addCrumb">
                <argument name="crumbName" xsi:type="string">Register</argument>
                <argument name="crumbInfo" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Register</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Register</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
```

**3. Add following code to list.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml(); ?>
```

All above codes are not working.

Comment: Please check option already available at the config side
1.Log into your Magento Admin Panel with your username and password
2.Navigate to System/ Configuration/ Web/ Default Pages
3. In Show Breadcrumbs for CMS Pages, choose yes to get Breadcrumbs disabled

Comment: Yes i have check it but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Please add into your layout file

```
<referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" template="Magento_Catalog::product/breadcrumbs.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Breadcrumbs</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks Bro but its not working for me

Comment: I think yours answer for magento 1.9 not 2.2